# How to read big csv file from disk line by line in React?

Tags: reactjs, csv, bigdata

I have a big data type of csv file. I want to read line by line.I don't want memory overflow. I'm looking for this but i don't find. The methods I saw did not work in React or i can't work. Example,

`fs.createReadStream('path/to/my.csv')
  .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
  .on('data', row => console.log(row))`

i found this and i say, yeaah this is awesome but i get error like "createReadStream not a function" from React. Please help, this is so important for me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
var fs = require('fs');   

     let readStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/my.csv);
            let rows = [];

            // Handle any errors while reading
            readStream.on('error', err => {
                // handle error

            });

            // Listen for data
            readStream.on('data', chunk => {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            // File is done being read
            readStream.on('close', () => {
                // Create a buffer of the image from the stream

            });
```

Comment: Hi, createReadStream method not working in React for me. I while use get error.(Type Error: fs.createReadStream is not a function)

Comment: I think you cannot use fs module into reactjs , the fs module needs to be executed with nodejs , Or if you want only to display data use this package  https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv

Comment: I want to read and some processing on data. Actually I want, a loop. Per loop give me a line from csv. I think it's not difficult but why i dont found and not understand.

Comment: Promise with loop

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you explain?